# Qual a origem da expressão "Pegar o baba"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, ordem-de-expressões

Na Bahia tem-se o Costume de falar "Vamos pegar o baba" ou "Vamos pegar esse baba hoje" se referindo a jogar futebol ou qualquer outro jogo coletivo com bola.

Comment: Isto não é resposta, mas talvez seja útil. O dicionário Houaiss restringe esse sentido de "baba" à Bahia; mas indica também, sem restrição geográfica (mas em Portugal nunca ouvi), *baba* como 'jogadores sem condição para jogar na equipa principal'. E encontra-se na revista Placar e outras, já nos anos 70, coisas como "o time estava uma baba", que creio que significa 'estava fraco". *Um baba* = 'jogo de futebol de rua' já aparece num livro em 1958, portanto já é coisa com alguns anos.

Comment: Talvez de baba = mole = fraco, para descrever jogadores em má forma? E daí para jogo de amadores de rua?

Comment: @Jacinto, não sei se deveria comentar, já que o comentário é velho, mas… Eu já ouvi e já usei muito "baba" como "fácil"; ex.: "esse jogo é baba" (esse jogo é fácil). Outro exemplo é "eles 'tavam (uma) baba".(eles estavam uma baba de ganhar; eles estavam fáceis de ganhar). Talvez tenha relação.

Answer (score 1):

"Bater um baba" seria a forma adequada. As bolas de couro, antigamente, quando molhadas, produziam uma "baba" (um líquido pastoso ou denso e ficavam lisas/escorregadias como quiabos. Um antigo goleiro do Atlético Paranaense, o Altevir, em uma entrevista, falava das bolas de couro do seu tempo que ficavam lisas, gosmentas parecendo baba de quiabo...